# Can we force spark to save partitions, from two PairRDDs, with the same key on the same machines?

Tags: java, join, apache-spark, hdfs, rdd

I am working with Spark on top of a HDFS cluster.
Before a join operation in Java Spark between two (key,value) PairRDDs, I partition data of both files with a HashPartitioner to have elements with the same key on the same machine. That's fine for each file independently, but as mentioned in a previous post [When create two different Spark Pair RDD with same key set, will Spark distribute partition with same key to the same machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368202/when-create-two-different-spark-pair-rdd-with-same-key-set-will-spark-distribut), partitioned RDDs are not necessarily co-located, so the same keys from both RDDs may not be on the same machine.

Is there a way to force spark to do that? to be sure that same keys from different PairRDDs are on the same machine

Btw since we use a hashpartitioning, for both RDDs same keys are in the same partition number but the order of the machines on which partitions are saved is different from one RDD to the other.

For example, if we have 'N' machines, is there a way to attribute a number to each machine (I guess spark do this internally),
and then simply force the partition number 'P' to be written on the machine 'N modulo P'?

Comment: Could you explain why do you want this?

Comment: For code efficiency, so that when joining the two RDDs, spark spends less time shuffling data between nodes since all of the same keys would be on one machine only, thus join tasks would be done internally to each machine and not between different nodes.